# Comparing two values in different Excel sheets

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have two Excel files. I have to compare two columns: if the column of the first Excel sheet matches the column of another Excel sheet, and also their value, the code should return those rows.

I have tried this code, but I am getting an error:

```
import tkinter as tk
import pandas as pd
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename

 # --- functions ---

def work_with_data(data1, data2):

 print(data1.head())
 print(data2.head())

# ... here you can works with data1, data2 ...


def get_filenames():
# default values before reading data

 data1 = None
 data2 = None

# first filename and data1

 filename1 = askopenfilename(filetypes =[('CSV files', '*.csv')])

 if filename1:
    lbl1['text'] = filename1
    data1 = pd.read_csv(filename1)
 else:
    lbl1['text'] = 'Filename 1 not selected'

# second filename and data2

filename2 = askopenfilename(filetypes =[('CSV files', '*.csv')])

if filename2:
    lbl2['text'] = filename2
    data2 = pd.read_csv(filename2)
else:
    lbl2['text'] = 'Filename 2 not selected'

# start working with data

if data1 is not None and data2 is not None:
   work_with_data(data1, data2)
data1["Facility"] ='FALSE'
#data1.loc[:, 'FOOD_TYPE']= data1['FOOD_TYPE'].astype(str)
#data2.loc[:, 'val']= data2['val'].astype(str)
data1.loc[data1["POI_NAME"].isin( data2["chain id"] ) & 
(data1["FOOD_TYPE"]==data2["val"]),["Facility"]] = 'TRUE'
#data1.loc[:, 'FOOD_TYPE']= data1['FOOD_TYPE'].astype(float)
#data2.loc[:, 'val']= data2['val'].astype(float)
data1.to_csv("C:/Users/patesari/Desktop/python work/practice1.csv")
# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()
#root.geometry('200x200')

lbl1 = tk.Label(root, text='Select filename 1')
lbl1.pack(side='top', pady=10)

lbl2 = tk.Label(root, text='Select filename 2')
lbl2.pack(side='top', pady=10)

btn = tk.Button(root, text='Open', command=get_filenames)
btn.pack(side='top', pady=10)

root.mainloop()
```

below is the snipet of my excel
[Excel 1:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8AVZq.png)
[Excel 2:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k48k3.png)
I am getting the below error

```
return self.func(*args)
File "chainid.py", line 48, in get_filenames
data1.loc[data1["POI_NAME"].isin( data2["chain id"] ) & 
(data1["FOOD_TYPE"]==data2["val"]),["Facility"]] = 'TRUE'

File "C:\Users\patesari\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-
32\lib\site- 
packages\pandas\core\ops.py", line 1676, in wrapper
raise ValueError("Can only compare identically-labeled "
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects
```

Even I tried coverting the value to string. then too its givivng me an error

Comment: Could you please provide us with a sample of data1 and data2?

Comment: I have added the snippet of my data

Answer (score 0):

I've never used `tkinter` so it's not totally clear to me what's going on in the beginning there but generally it should be pretty easy to compare columns using pandas and return rows where there is some overlap. Your issue is with how your are defining that overlap.

I suggest first combining the dataframes, and then performing your checks.

```py
# merge dataframes
new_df = pd.merge(data1, data2, how='outer', left_on=['POI_NAME'], right_on=['chain id'])
# first check
new_df = new_df[new_df['POI_NAME'].isin(new_df['chain id'].values)]
# second check
new_df = new_df[new_df['FOOD_TYPE'] == new_df['val']]
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: If any of the value in data1["POI_NAME"] matches data2["chain id"] then the second column of data1["FOOD_TYPE"] should also match data2["val"])

Comment: Added a suggestion, still not clear on how you are defining overlap between those dataframes. Hopefully joining on `POI_NAME/chain id` will work for you.

Comment: i am getting the below error.   return self.func(*args)
  File "foodtype.py", line 54, in get_filenames
    new_df = new_df[new_df['POI_NAME'].isnin(new_df['chain id'].values)]
  File "C:\Users\patesari\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 5067, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'isnin'

Comment: Yep was a typo. `isnin` should be `isin`.

Comment: Still getting this error  return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 108, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 132, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1601, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1608, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'FOOD_TYPE'

Comment: I can't debug anything without some test data. Pictures don't work, please provide some code to create sample data frames for data1 and data2. You can use the form df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'col1': [0,1,2], 'col2': [3,4,5]})